# Android SDK Manager not opening on Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: android, sdk

Hi I have Intel based mac running OS X 10.8.4. I recently downloaded and installed the complete ADT bundle from android website. 
Eclipse is working fine. AVD Manager is also opening correctly. But, I am not able to run the SDK manager (neither from Eclipse nor from SDK/tools folder).

I get this message, when I run android file from sdk/tools folder.

```
> Last login: Sun Aug 18 23:31:59 on ttys000 unknown28cfe9126a3d:~
> princejindal$
> /Users/princejindal/Documents/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130717/sdk/tools/android
> ; exit; Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/android/utils/ILogger Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.android.utils.ILogger     at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) logout
> 
> [Process completed]
```

Can anyone let me know, how to resolve this?
I also tried to download and install the latest version of JDK (I know that it is pre-installed in mac).

I am clueless. Please help me resolve this issue.